# Format the output in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a excel sheet:

[image]

I read it out:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

excel_file = 'test.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name=0)
print(df)
```

it shows:

```
  name         value
0    a  10000.000000
1    b  20000.000000
2    c  30000.000000
3    d  40000.000000
4    e  50000.000000
5    f      1.142857
6    g      1.285714
```

how can I format the number output to like `%.2f`, can I format it directly by `print (df)` like add something in print like `%.2f`, or I must first modify it content and commit back to `df` and then print again?

UPDATE:

I try the answer below, `df['value'].apply("{0:.2f}".format)` doesn't work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

excel_file = 'test.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name=0)
print(df['value'])
df['value'].apply("{0:.2f}".format)
print(df['value'])
print(df)
```

it shows:

```
0    10000.000000          
1    20000.000000          
2    30000.000000          
3    40000.000000          
4    50000.000000          
5        1.142857          
6        1.285714          
Name: value, dtype: float64
0    10000.000000          
1    20000.000000          
2    30000.000000          
3    40000.000000          
4    50000.000000          
5        1.142857          
6        1.285714          
Name: value, dtype: float64
  name         value       
0    a  10000.000000       
1    b  20000.000000       
2    c  30000.000000       
3    d  40000.000000       
4    e  50000.000000       
5    f      1.142857       
6    g      1.285714
```

`pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.2f' % x)` works:

```
0   10000.00               
1   20000.00               
2   30000.00               
3   40000.00               
4   50000.00               
5       1.14               
6       1.29               
Name: value, dtype: float64
  name    value            
0    a 10000.00            
1    b 20000.00            
2    c 30000.00            
3    d 40000.00            
4    e 50000.00            
5    f     1.14            
6    g     1.29
```

Comment: do `df['value'] = df['value'].apply("{0:.2f}".format)` instead of just `df['value'].apply("{0:.2f}".format)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the float_format of pandas in pandas set_option like this

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.2f' % x)
```

If you want to change the formating of just one column, you can do a `apply` and change formating like this

```
df['age'].apply("{0:.2f}".format)

# Output

0    10000.00
1    20000.00
2    30000.00
3    40000.00
4    50000.00
5        1.14
6        1.29
Name: age, dtype: object
```

Comment: many thanks, could I convert it from `float` to `int` if it already a `float` in original data?

Comment: you can convert `float` column to `int` column easily with `df['age'].astype(int)`

Comment: seems `df['age'].astype(int)` and `df['age'].apply("{0:.2f}".format)` doesn't work, anyway, I will rise a new question later

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work.? Are you getting any error.? Both are working fine in my machine and I have provided the output in my answer

Comment: no error, just format not change, I update in my question

Comment: does this `"{0:.2f}"` shall be modified since my target column is not first 1?

Comment: Well, i see in your codes you are doing `df['value'].apply("{0:.2f}".format)` It wont change the dataframe, if you want to change the column you have to do `df['value'] = df['value'].apply("{0:.2f}".format)`

Comment: ah...yes, my mistake, maybe you could update your answer to avoid misunderstanding? to add `df['value] = `

Comment: If your issue is solved consider accepting the answer so that others can know it is solved

Answer (score 1):

The default `precision` is 6. You can override this this with [`pandas.set_option`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html):

```
pd.set_option('display.precision', 2)
```